# how to send http response message code:400 in python

Tags: python

I have written a web server in python and I want to send **HTTP response message codes:400** instead of the response "Website Coming Soon!" on any client-request, please tell how can I do this.

**The Server Code is:**

```
import socket
import re
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 13555

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)
print ("Serving HTTP on port %s ..." % PORT)

while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(2048)
    response = "Website Coming Soon!"   #this response should be http response message code:400
    http_response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"+"Content-Type: text/html\n"+"\n"+"<html><body>"+response+"</body></html>\n"
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    client_connection.close()
```

Comment: You need to send `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` instead of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` I don't see where you send content length.

Comment: now I am using http_response = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request\n"+"Content-Type: text/html\n" but the browser is showing nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try to get to know the protocol you're trying to speak :)

HTTP is fairly simple, all HTTP messages consist of 3 basic parts, of which the 3rd is optional:

- The request or status line (first line)
- The request headers, each on one line (or with some escaping spread over multiple), followed by an extra newline
- The request body, which is optional for most requests, and for some responses.

What you want to do is change the "status line" in a response message. Since you want to send the 400 status code, the first line in your response should be

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request
```

But there's two things wrong here:

1. You don't actually parse the request, so you can't really tell the client he's doing something wrong (all 4xx codes represent *client errors*)
2. Your sending the wrong message. Probably, what you want is something like `503 Service unavailable`

Dive into the [specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). They're *really*, *really* straight forward. And if you read it thoroughly, and start speaking HTTP the way it is intended, the world gets another tiny bit better ;)

Comment: now I am using

http_response = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request\n"+"Content-Type: text/html\n"

but the browser is showing nothing

Comment: You're missing the extra newline after the headers.

Comment: @SajalAli Please read the RFC 2616 before asking this kind of question. BTW you're missing "\r"s, yet this is CLEARLY documented in the RFC.